# Python not reading file/ executing code properly

Tags: python-3.x

I have a strange problem which I'm not sure why is occurring.

In a game, I type a command (::pos) which writes the positional coords to a .txt file. When I try automate this process (using win32com to type the command) and read the file, the previous coords are displayed instead of the current ones. This makes no sense as I update the coords before displaying them:

```
def add(self):
    id = self.myTextInput.text()
    shell.AppActivate('App title')
    # Update position file
    shell.SendKeys('::pos')
    shell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')
    # Add object
    shell.SendKeys('::object ' + id + ' 0')
    shell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')
    # Read position
    with open('.txt file path', 'r') as f:
        f = f.read().split()
        self.listWidget.addItem(id + ' ' + f[1] + ' ' + f[3] + ' 0')
```

The code is executed upon pressing a button 'add'. The weird thing is that it all works fine if I create a separate button and function called 'updatePos' (which I press before pressing 'add') but doesn't work if I just call the updatePos() function within add. I have also tried using sleeps to stagger commands but that seems to work strangely too (sleeps block of code before it, not sure if its the shell commands messing with it?).

I think the code is executing in an abnormal order perhaps? E.g. opening and reading text file before the position is updated - but not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I'm guessing that `::object` selects an object, and `::pos` dumps its position - in which case you would appear to be doing these commands in the wrong order.  In any case, a small delay to allow the game to actually write the file is likely to be necessary.

Comment: ::pos dumps the players current position and ::object spawns an object at that position, but the position coords are not needed for this (they are needed later on). I tried adding in a sleep(n) between the two but it seems to sleep for n seconds before executing either of the commands? Not sure why

Comment: The examples I've found for SendKeys usage from Python have all used `win32api.Sleep(500)` for delays, rather than Python's `time.sleep()` - that might be worth a try, I can't see anything else that might cause a problem.

Comment: Still halts everything for some reason! Put it right between the two commands but it acts as if I put it before them both

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file before you can read in the changes.

try adding f.close() to the end of this.

Comment: I'm using 'with open' so the file should be closed automatically after the nested block is executed? I tried adding f.close() anyway and it hasn't seemed to solve my problem

Comment: ah, can you show the other part of the code. This is the automation code right? can you show the part that this is calling / using.